# Antipodal map of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $A: S^2 \to S^2$ be the antipodal map between spheres, we know that it induces the endomorphism $-1$ on the $\pi_2(S^2)=Z$. Consider the composite $S^2 \xrightarrow{A} S^2 \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb{R}P^2$, the second arrow being the quotient map. Now this map is the same as the projection map $\pi:S^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$, and the projection map being a covering space map induces an isomorphism between $\pi_2(S^2)$ and $\pi_2(\mathbb{R}P^2)$. Now, it follows that $\pi_* = A_* \pi_* = -\pi_*$ as maps $\pi_2(S^2) \to \pi_2(\mathbb{R}P^2)$. Isn't that a contradiction? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: By the way, you mean $\pi_* A_*$ - although  $A_*$ does not exist ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Note that $A$ is not basepoint-preserving. This way, you can not just apply the functor $\pi_*$ to the commuting triangle $S^2 \xrightarrow{A} S^2 \to P^2.$ Indeed, recall why the projection gives an isomorphism: having $S^n \to P^2$ you choose a lift $S^n \to S^2$ by lifting the map piece by piece on trivializing neighborhoods, *starting from the neighborhood of the basepoint*. Without the basepoint, you'd have two choices of the first step and will potentially have two listings - that's not a bijection.